# The user name for the recipient is invalid. Envelope definition is missing a UserName for recipientId

Tags: docusignapi

Hope your doing alright, and that someone could help see what i'm doing wrong :

i'm using docusign here in this function i'm getting the firstname and lastname of the signer :

```
public function validate(Request $request)
{
        $valideur = User::find($devi->id_assigne);
        $signer2 = array(
            "firstname" =>   $valideur->firstname,
            "lastname" => $valideur->lastname,
       
    );
     
       $name = $signer2["firstname"];
       $this->sends($name);
```

}

And in this second function i try to get the value of firstname and lastname to send it
through docusign  :

```
public function sends($name)

{   
    $this->args = $this->getTemplateArgs();
   
    $args = $this->args;
   
    $envelope_args = $args["envelope_args"];
   
    $envelope_definition = $this->makeEnvelopeFileObject($args["envelope_args"],$name);
    
    $apiClient = new ApiClient();
           
    $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(config('app.auth_server')); 
    try{
        $accessToken = $this->getToken($apiClient);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
    }
    
    
    
    $userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
    $accountInfo = $userInfo[0]->getAccounts();
    $apiClient->getConfig()->setHost($accountInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . config('app.sufix'));  
    
    $apiClient->getConfig()->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
    
    
    $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

    
    $results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelope_definition);
   
    $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();

   
    $authentication_method = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
    $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
    'authentication_method' => $authentication_method,
    'client_user_id' => '1000',
    'recipient_id' => '1',
    'return_url' => $envelope_args['ds_return_url'],
    'user_name' => $name  , 'email' =>''
    ]);

    $results = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelope_id,
    $recipient_view_request);
```

when i dump the value name i got the correct value but i don't understand why i got this erreur "The user name for the recipient is invalid. Envelope definition is missing a UserName for recipientId"

Answer (score 0):

You should have code like this somewhere, I didn't see it in your question. The information below is sufficient to create an envelope with embedded signing.

```
    # Create the signer recipient model
    $signer = new Signer(
        [ # The signer
            'email' => $args['signer_email'],
            'name' => $args['signer_name'],
            'recipient_id' => "1",
            'routing_order' => "1",
            # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
            'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
        ]
    );
```

[Dump of the value Firstname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n09St.png)
[Docusign Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVfb.png)

[mail picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeGtX.png)

Comment: i have this lines of codes in another function makeenvelope. i'm trying to get this information from a  database.                                                                                     
thanks for your help

Comment: and when i'm redirected to docusign i don't have the name of the signer i got  :{signer}

Comment: This sounds like a different issue than the error you talked about in the question. What is the issue you face?

Comment: i used the solution you gave me using $args['signer_name']  in both  $signer = new Signer(....) and in $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([ ... 'username'=$args['signer_name'] ) and the error doesn't display anymore. but when i'am redirected to docusign and i try to sign the document i don't get the name in the tab sign i have {signer } also in the mail the name isn't displayed : Hello {Signer}  : not the value of the name like(jane)

Comment: That's cause you need to put the right values for name and email, I don't know what they are for you

Comment: i got the value of name and email from database because the signer could differ

Comment: when i dump the value it's shown that it's correct but when i try to sign or when i got the email the name isn't displayed only {signer} is shown.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: i've added screenshot in the main post 3picture from the dump result /mail/docusign. Want i want is to have Marie-therese in the place of signer

Comment: Then just where it says  $name = $signer2["firstname"]; change this to  $name = "Marie-therese";

Comment: but the firstname change:  for this one is $name = "Marie-therese" but for another it could be "julie" that why i use  this form $name = $signer2["firstname"]                 
Hope that we can find a solution i tried  many thing but its doesn't work

Comment: You need to debug what is the value of $signer2["firstname"]  and do you not want last name too?

Comment: $signer2["firstname"] ="Marie-therese"  that what i got when i debug. yes i do want both but now i'm more focus on having only the firstname in the fist place and then i can do the same for lastname. thank you soo much for your patience and your help

Comment: It should be $signer2["name"] not $signer2["firstname"], sorry about the confusion